# Using ASP.NET Mail with an outgoing server that requires SSL

Tags: asp.net, ssl, email

I am trying to send an email in ASP.NET using system.net.mail

the problem is that the outgoing server requires a secure connection (SSL)

Does anyone know how I can implement this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample with GMail which uses SSL:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("youraccount@gmail.com", "secret");

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.From = new MailAddress("youraccount@gmail.com");
        mail.To.Add("youraccount@gmail.com");
        mail.Subject = "Test mail";
        mail.Body = "test body";
        client.Send(mail);
    }
}
```